# how do I use keying in compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video

I have this scene with a green screen in it but when i try to use compositing something goes wrong. what can i do so that only the green screen is affected with an image of my choice. here is my setup:[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm confused by your setup. Did you add a green background to one of the layers to then take it away later using a chroma key? That seems unnecessary to me. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more detail on what you did.

Comment: I've  decided to use the masking tool instead of a green screen now so it works. Should I answer the question or delete it now that I have an answer?

Comment: Please write an answer.maybe someone with a similar question will find it useful